# Daily coding problem 18: Maximums of k-sized windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge

**The challenge**

Given an array of integers and a number k, where 1 <= k <= length of the array, compute the maximum values of each subarray of length k.

For example, given array = [10, 5, 2, 7, 8, 7] and k = 3, we should get: [10, 7, 8, 8], since:

- 10 = max(10, 5, 2)
- 7 = max(5, 2, 7)
- 8 = max(2, 7, 8)
- 8 = max(7, 8, 7)

Do this in O(n) time and O(k) space. You can modify the input array in-place and you do not need to store the results. You can simply print them out as you compute them.

**My question**

This was posed as a hard coding challenge. My confusion is that I solved the problem in 5 lines of code. Either the code doesn't achieve the correct time complexity (which I think it does), or this challenge has been incorrectly categorised. Please can someone review my code to see if it is correct.

```
array = [10,5,2,7,8,7,9]
k = 4

for index in range (len(array)-(k-1)):
    print(max(array[index:index+k]))
```

Comment: Unless I am mistaken, that is O(nk) time, not O(n). Btw, your program works only for k=3.

Comment: Rev 2 is still O(n k) time.

Comment: How is this O(nk) time? I thought for loops run in O(n) time and as there are no nested loops this should just be an O(n) time-frame? Why is this not the case? Thanks

Comment: The `max(i:i+k)` operation is a nested loop, and runs in O(k), and you perform it n times, making the total time complexity O(n k).